# Rails ajax call to controller not getting response back

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Making a simple GET request to the controller action. Debugged to make sure it's actually making a request and there are no issues with the controller executing the action. However, it is not succeeding as I am not seeing a response being logged.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: _url,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  sucess: function(response) {
    alert(response);
    console.log("response: " + response);
  }
});
```

```html
  def get_team_statuses
    @wager = Wager.find(params[:id])
    _team_count = helpers.get_team_member_names_without_self(@wager).count + 1
    _opponent_count = helpers.get_opposing_member_names(@wager).count

    _team_full = _team_count == @wager.team_size.players_count
    _opposing_team_full = _opponent_count == @wager.team_size.players_count

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: {team_full: _team_full, opposing_team_full: _opposing_team_full } }
    end
  end
```

Looked up a bunch of resources including documentation and it seems like it's wired up correctly. Only interesting message I get is

Started GET "/wagers/1b4b6da7-7dd0-4a42-b17b-3872850d908d/get-team-statuses" for ::1 at 2020-08-10 16:11:01 -0700
Processing by WagersController#get_team_statuses as JSON

**[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.09ms)**

Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)

Any ideas?

Edit: this is what my network tab looks like for xhr requests. As you can see I clicked the button 3 times to send the requests so there are 3 listed.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use the developer tools network tab to see xhr requests that have made? Is there any problem with it?

Comment: @NinhLe it doesn't seem like it, it says 200 OK. Any other way I might be able to debug this?

Comment: hmm, have you check the preview or response tab? Did it empty?

Comment: @NinhLe what do you mean by the preview or response tab, and whether it emptied or not? I may be unfamiliar with that

Comment: Using chrome developer tool, sorry that my mistake to not clarify, like [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference) beside the header tab

Comment: @NinhLe Ok I checked and it didn't empty. I've edited my question to include the image of the xhr request tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will fix:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: _url,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
    console.log("response: " + response);
  }
});
```

You have made a typo error between `success` and `sucess`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. I wish there was some sort of syntax highlighting or error message in the console that could've alerted me to that earlier. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm using vscode, but unfortunately no syntax error highlights